# DIV wrapping around a IMG with 100% height

Tags: css

I have a DIV and a IMG both set to 100% height and widths are auto.

But I want the DIV to resize/wrap to the width of the IMG (and maintain its aspect ratio) while resizing height of the browser. Only this doesn't seem to do so. In any browser. Anybody knows why this behavior occurs?

```
div {
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

img {
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}

<div>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Official_portrait_of_Barack_Obama.jpg"/>
</div>
```

You can try it out here. The div has a red background.
http://jsfiddle.net/jjktF/3/

Thanks!

Comment: can you clarify resizing the browser? is this a popup windw? what is your base height, the size of the image? height:100% is based on the height of the parent element, and will only work if the parent element has an explicit height set.

Comment: @Matt.C It should stretch itself a 100% to the height of it's parent. Eventually it will be the window. The image is behaving correctly. Its just the div that won't 'rewrap' itself around the image.

After resizing the browser, the image scales like it should. The div is left behind. When pressing RUN again in jsfiddle. The div wraps itself again. It's like the div only sets it's own width once.

Comment: Can you not just put a 20px red border on the img element and make the image fill the space required with display:block; and assigning a width or height?

Answer (score 2):

hey i hope this will help you see mentioned below **CSS**

```
div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

its working as per your requirement.......

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jjktF/11/)

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/jjktF/15/)

Comment: You don't need to set any `height` properties for the DIV of the IMG tags. Also, your second jsFiddle is incomplete.  You need to set some `display` properties. http://jsfiddle.net/jjktF/16/

Comment: @hungerstar i have given the example of responsive image..... check my answer....its resizing according to our screen size....

Comment: I did, use a 200px wide image for `DEMO2` then you'll have that "ah-ha!" moment.  Actually, I'll do it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jjktF/17/.  Also, you have descender height showing in your `DEMO2`.

Comment: Mehhhh thanks guys. But maybe my question isn't being understood. I want my image to behave like it does here http://jsfiddle.net/jjktF/3/ . It's just that the div doesn't go along with it.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the width of your div the same as the width of your image perhaps?

Comment: Post suggestions as a note and not as an answer.

Comment: They are both auto 'cause they need to scale along.

Comment: Oh i see, i'm pretty new to this. P.s for some reason i can't add a comment to the question

Comment: That's because you need to earn reputation to do so. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 0):

You can set div width like this.

```
 div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The image won't keep it's original aspect ratio this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-width: 100%;` or `width: 100%;` so the image will re-size.  The difference is that `max-width` will prevent the image from scaling above its original dimensions where `width` will scale to fit the containing element.

- i.e. if your image is 100px by 100px and the containing element is 400px wide, using `max-width` the image will only scale up to 100px by 100px where with `width` it would scale up to 400px by 400px and become grainy.

After that it's just a matter of determining how you're going to wrap your "border" (container element) around the image.  You can do this one of two ways:

- set your "border" (container element) to `display: inline-block; http://jsfiddle.net/wp2eS/
- or - float your "border" (container element) http://jsfiddle.net/wp2eS/1/

*CSS*

```css
img {
     max-width: 100%;
     /* or */
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
}
```

Using `display: block;` on the image removes the space that appears below the image due to the fact that the image is by default an inline element and that space is due to descender height.  Floating the "border" (container element) would have the same effect.

*HTML*

```html
<span class="frame">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/" />
</span>
```

If you are going to use a simple one color border I would probably just use the CSS `border` property on the image itself.

Comment: Thanks hungerstar!

But the red color is just helper. I need to have the image size a 100% height to the window. And I want the div to auto size it's width to the width of the image. Like here http://jsfiddle.net/jjktF/3/ . The image does it correctly, the div doesn't when resizing the browser height.